# RxJava 2 in Spring boot 1.5.6

Tags: java, spring, rx-java

I have restController which return for example Single object

> ```
> @ApiOperation(value="Create new user")
> public Single<CreatedUserResponse> saveNewUser(@RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) {
>     return userService.saveUser(userRequest)
>             .map(e -> {
>                 CreatedUserResponse response = new CreatedUserResponse(e.getUserId());
>                 Link link=linkTo(methodOn(UserController.class)
>                 .getUserById(e.getUserId(),userRequest.getUserId()))
>                         .withSelfRel();
>                 response.add(link);
>                 return response;
>             });
> }
> ```

I got following error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:187) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]

I chang from Single to CreatedUserResponse and everything works fine, so when i change from reactive type to normal it works but what i had to do if i want to return reactive type? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

RxJava 2 is supported from Spring Boot 2.0

Docs : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/

This repo has the wrapper in returning rx java 2 types :

https://github.com/jmnarloch/rxjava-spring-boot-starter

Also you can convert into Defered or Future type and return as suggested here :

http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2015/03/using-rx-java-observable-in-spring-mvc.html

Comment: I know that spring boot 1 support rxjava 1 but i once found solution for dealing with it and suing rxjava 2. I am looking for solution to use rxjava 2 with spring boot 1

Comment: you should return CreatedUserResponse as part of the handler method in order for spring HttpMessageConverters to convert it appropriate response(as spring boot 1 doesnt know how to convert RXjava types)  or you can define your own HttpMessageConverter and handle it there.

Comment: you can see these tutorials for wiring up custom httpmessageconverter : 1) http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest 2) http://richardchesterwood.blogspot.in/2015/02/writing-custom-http-message-converter.html.